# Ruby gem sample_form

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am using Rails 4.1.6 & Ruby 2.1.5

I want drop-down for all date ie. 1st drop-down should be for Month, 2nd drop-down should be for Date & Last drop-down will be for Year.

M using `daterangepicker-bs3` & `sample_form gem`.

i written in `_form.hatml.haml`

```
= f.input :date_of_birth,order: [:month,:year]
```

So now Month & Year is coming in drop-down. I want date also in drop-down between of month & year, ie. month, date, year format.

For this I tried in same way:

```
= f.input :date_of_birth,order: [:month,:date,:year]
```

after putting date, it shows error

> "stack level too deep"

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a simple spelling error. You want `:day`, not `:date`.